# Can I assume linear independence for range $T = \{Tv_1, ..., Tv_n\}$ where $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is linearly independent and doesn't belong to null $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. If $\{u_1, ..., u_m, v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, where $\{u_1, ..., u_n\}$ spans the null space, can I automatically assume that $\{Tv_1, ..., Tv_n\}$ is linearly independent?

I have seen this several times now but found no convincing proof  for it. Perhaps I am overlooking the obvious.

Comment: Assume they are dependent and see what you get.

Comment: Question in title: answer is no, question in body: answer is yes. You should prove this using the definition of linear independence, and the fact that $T$ is linear

Comment: Thanks, I realised the question is posed differently in title and body ... hope this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:

$c_1Tv_1+c_2Tv_2+...+c_nTv_n = 0 \\
\implies T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n) = 0\\
\implies c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n \in Null(T)$

So we can write:

$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n = d_1u_1+d_2u_2+...+d_nu_n$

Since the $\{u_1, ..., u_m, v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is independent, all $c$'s and $d$'s are 0.

So $\{Tv_1, ..., Tv_n\}$ is independent.

Comment: I like this proof, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Tv_i$ are linearly dependent. Then $\exists c_i$ not all $0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_iTv_i=0$.

This gives $T(\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i)=0$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i$ belongs to the null-space of $T$.

Since $u_i$ span the null-space, this would mean $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i=\sum_{j=1}^mC_ju_j$ which violates the linear independence of basis vectors.

Comment: Yes, I can follow - thanks!

Comment: Have you, by mistake, downvoted both our answers? @tobkloeff

Comment: I didn't mean to and don't know how this happened ... sorry if I did, I'm still new to the forum.

Comment: @Shubham Johri. That's impossible with the OPs reputation. He can't downvote yet.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, just checking.